# PyTorch LSTM has nan for MSELoss

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, gradient-descent

My model is:

```
class BaselineModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feature_dim=5, hidden_size=5, num_layers=2, batch_size=32):
        super(BaselineModel, self).__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=feature_dim,
                            hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        return lstm_out, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        hidden = Variable(next(self.parameters()).data.new(
            self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
        cell = Variable(next(self.parameters()).data.new(
            self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
        return (hidden, cell)
```

Training looks like:

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, **params)

model = BaselineModel(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, weight_decay=0.0001)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

for epoch in range(250):

    # hidden = (torch.zeros(2, 13, 5),
    #           torch.zeros(2, 13, 5))
    # model.hidden = hidden
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        hidden = model.init_hidden(13)
        inputs = data[0]
        outputs = data[1]

        print('inputs',  inputs.size())
        # print('outputs', outputs.size())

        # optimizer.zero_grad()
        model.zero_grad()

        # print('inputs', inputs)
        pred, hidden = model(inputs, hidden)

        loss = loss_fn(pred, outputs)

        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
        optimizer.step()

        print('Epoch: ', epoch, '\ti: ', i, '\tLoss: ', loss)
```

I have gradient clipping set already, which seems to be the recommended solution. But after even the first step, I get:

> Epoch:  0       i:  0   Loss:  tensor(nan, grad_fn=)

Comment: Why is the hidden initialization repeated at for iteration. Also what's the `data[0]` and `data[1]`?

Comment: Those are my tensors of inputs / outputs

Comment: And I initialize at each iteration because my input/output are batches of data

Comment: What's the shape and example tensors? `Wx + b` are chained state-wise across the RNN sausage, so knowing the `x` is important =)

Comment: Shape of input is: `[10, 32, 161]` (seq_length, batch, dimension)

Comment: The shapes doesn't matter because the forward and backpropagation passes through, it's the content, what is the value inside the tensors that the layers are multiplying? `print('data')` =)

Comment: PyTorch already has an LSTM implementation - [torch.nn.LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html). If your goal is to implement from scratch, you can [find here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Advanced-Deep-Learning-with-Python/tree/master/Chapter07) a working solution with PyTorch 1.3.1. If you run [this example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Advanced-Deep-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/Chapter07/lstm_gru_count_1s.py), the network will achieve 100% test accuracy in 5-6 epochs.

Comment: What is the loss after just computing it? Are there nans? I may be a problem with the inputs/outputs as indicated by [alvas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/610569/alvas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your issue has to do with your outputs / `data[1]` (it would help if you show examples of your train_set). Running the following piece of code gives no nan, but I forced shape of output by hand before calling the `loss_fn(pred, outputs)` :

```
class BaselineModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feature_dim=5, hidden_size=5, num_layers=2, batch_size=32):
        super(BaselineModel, self).__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=feature_dim,
                            hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        return lstm_out, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        hidden = Variable(next(self.parameters()).data.new(
            self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
        cell = Variable(next(self.parameters()).data.new(
            self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size))
        return (hidden, cell)

model = BaselineModel(batch_size=32)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, weight_decay=0.0001)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

hidden = model.init_hidden(10)
model.zero_grad()
pred, hidden = model(torch.randn(2,10,5), hidden)
pred.size() #torch.Size([2, 10, 5])
outputs = torch.zeros(2,10,5)

loss = loss_fn(pred, outputs)
loss

loss.backward()
torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
optimizer.step()
print(loss)
```

Please note a common reason for nan values can be related to numerical stability of your learning phase, but usually you have values for the first steps before you see the divergence happening, which is apparently not the case here.